# How to find out which element hold the data object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I pass the data object to a function as in:

```
$("#someobject").data({
    "prp1":"x",
    "dosomething":function(){
    callthisfunction(this);  //<---- HERE the data ref is sent to a function
   }
});

...
function callthisfunction(in_data)
{
  //how is the data element?
  var theElementHoldingTheDataIs = in_data.????;  //<--- how can I get $("#someobject")


}
```

My questions is: is there a way from data to inform to which object it depends on or belong to?

Comment: How and when called `dosomething` function?

Comment: As your code stands, `callthisfunction` is never being executed, so the question is moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure:

```
var obj = $("#someobject");
obj.data({
    "prp1": "x",
    "dosomething": (function(scope) {
        return function() {
            callthisfunction(scope); //<---- HERE the data ref is sent to a function
        }
    })(obj)
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9G9at/)

---

Or if you just want to send the data object:

```
var obj = $("#someobject");
obj.data({
    "prp1": "x",
    "dosomething": (function(scope) {
        return function() {
            callthisfunction(scope.data());
        }
    })(obj)
});
```